# What is spectral flow symmetry?

Tags: algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, string-theory

I can't find much about this, and am looking into this to satisfy personal curiosity.  I will like to know what spectral flow is, and what spectral flow symmetry is. I tried looking for this on Wikipedia but there is nothing on this. There are some papers that seem to use this, but I am looking for a stupid simple description of this stuff that still retains full meaning of what it really is. If there is some simple example of this, it will be really good. I am curious as to how this is used in physics.

Comment: Try checking out http://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cmb/v39/cmb1996v39.0460-0467.pdf, that might be a starting point for spectral flow.

Comment: The definition in the context of heterotic strings (or N=2 superconformal algebras in general), can be found in section 3 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3404 . Not sure if the meaning there is the same as what you are trying to learn more about...